# SharePoint Designer - Import "image" in WorkFlow(StringBuilder)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, email

I create WorkFlow that sends e-mail message. I want to import image(logo of company) in my email with  **SharePoint Designer(WorkFlow(Proporties) -> String Builder)**.

> **This is my code :**

**

[image: screenshot1]

> **This is result :**

**

[image: screenshot2]

> **Аny idea how to do that?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image will not be rendered in the page in which you are looking for(SharePoint Designer Workflow configuration page), just publish your workflow and then check the email sent by your workflow, the email body will have the image, if your email doesn't have the image, then try with below solutions,

1. The first thing I would check is to ensure the link is correct. Copy the URL from the link in the email and paste it into your web browser and see if it renders there.
2. Ensure that your email client is downloading images. You can add the sender of the email (SharePoint) to the safe senders list in Outlook, that way it will always download those images.
3. Try to put your image into picture library and try, for more information, check this [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/8110.sharepoint-2010-asset-versus-picture-library.aspx)

For more information on 3rd party free tool, have a look at the below link,

[Embed image in a SharePoint outgoing email using SharePoint Designer workflow activities](http://dcsharepointchick.blogspot.in/2013/09/embed-image-in-sharepoint-outgoing.html)

Comment: This is Not work :(

Comment: Please tell me an easy way to add logo in the message.